# How to generate typescript interface from a dojo i18n declaration?

Tags: javascript, dojo, typescript

Dojo declares an i18n package like so:

```
define({root: { "fooName": "fooValue" });
```

In typescript I can do this:

```
var root = { root: { "uom": { "Degrees": "Degrees" } } };
export = root;
```

But tsc -d test.ts doesn't generate anything useful as far as I can tell:

```
declare var root: {
    root: {
        "uom": {
            "Degrees": string;
        };
    };
};
export = root;
```

What I would really like is for tsc to generate a usable interface:

```
interface IResx {
    "uom": {
        "Degrees": string;
    };
};
```

Am I overlooking something?  How do we generate reusable d.ts files from a module like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a tiny node utility which requires two parameters.  The first is the interface name and the second is a path to a javascript file.  The javascript file must be very simple (e.g. require({root: {foo: "bar"}})):

```
var fs = require("fs");
var name = process.argv[2];
var file = process.argv[3];

function asInterface(o) {
  var result = "";
  for (var key in o) {
    if (!o.hasOwnProperty(key)) continue;
    var type = typeof o[key];
    if (type === "object") {
        result += key + ":{" + asInterface(o[key]) + "};\n";
    } else {
        result += key + ":" + type + ";\n";
    }
  }
  return result;
}

var target = file.substring(0, file.length - 3) + ".d.ts";

global.define = function (foo) {
  var result = "interface " + name + " {\n" + asInterface(foo.root) + "}\n";
  console.log(target, result);
  fs.writeFile(target, result);
}

var resx = require(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the definition file by hand. Or just ship your .ts file. :) TSC won't generate .d.ts files and there is no utility, to date, that will do such a thing.

.d.ts files are generally created when the original .js file wasn't created from TypeScript.

Comment: tsc -d generates .d.ts files

Comment: Well, I learn something new every day. Interesting how life can sometimes point you to other conclusions. :)

Answer (score 0):

If there is no existing .d.ts definitions file for a javascript library, (which appears to be the case with Dojo), you can suppress the typescript error by using ambient declarations.

To start, you can just do:

```
declare function define(x);
```

That will get rid of the compiler error when you use

```
define({root: { "fooName": "fooValue" }});
```

It doesn't, however, say much about what define() expects.  You can expand the declaration to provide more information. (Note, I'm not familiar with dojo, so these are just examples)

```
// specify that define doesn't return anything
declare function define(x): void;

// be explicit that parameter can be type 'any'
declare function define(x: any): void;

// declare any additional optional parameters, too
declare function define(x: any, y?: number, z? string): void;
```

Finally, you can define an interface when a particular structure is expected:

```
interface DojoI18nDefinition {
    root: { [key: string]: string; };
}

declare function define(x: DojoI18nDefinition): void;
```

Now typescript knows what x is, and will give an error if it's used wrong.  Now if you saved this to dojo.d.ts, you would have something reusable.  This is all that existing .d.ts files do; the difficultly is in making something that is complete, accurate, and handles any corner cases.

Comment: This isn't a library/compiler issue...just looking for type safety on string resources.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way of describing a behavior in TypeScript. What `-d` generates is fine behavior wise but its easier to simply write it by hand and make is more *open*

Comment: The thing is I have hundreds of resources and I'd like strong type-checking on them.  I believe I need to create a converter which takes an instance of root as input and generates an interface.

Comment: You could write a small utility to replace `declare var root:` with `interface SomeNameYouWant`and then use `interface SomeNameYouWant` within you app to refer to data that has this structure.